# Java search max args in method main

Tags: java, find, program-entry-point

I have a problem with finding the largest argument in method main in Java. For example, I give five numbers and I want to draw the greatest of them. I'm waiting for help and any ideas. Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Your English is fine, but you need to give us a bit more information if you want any useful help.  What have you tried so far?  Can you share your code please?

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing arguments to the program, you can use the following approach:

- Loop through the arguments passed to the program.
- Use `Integer.parseInt(string)` to get the integer form of a `String`<sup>1</sup>.
- Check if this integer is higher than the actual `max`:

  - If it is, then update the actual `max`

---

**Code:**

```
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE; // default value if no arguments were passed

for (String s : args) {
    if (Integer.parseInt(s) > max) {
        max = Integer.parseInt(s);
    }
}

System.out.println(max); // show
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test{ 

   public static void main(String args[]){
   int max = args[0];
      for(int i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
        if(max<args[i])
        {max = args[i];}
    }
    system.out.println(max);
   }
}
```